# how to add json array inside another existing array

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I want to update an existing array by adding new json array to it. How can this be done in swift.Thanks in Advance

Example:

```
new array = ["s","g"]
existing array = [ ["a","b"],["c","e","f"],[add new array here],["d"],["z","x"] ]
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You mention a "json array". What does that mean? JSON is a serialization format for transferring data structures over a serial channel like TCP/IP. JSON is not an array. It can contain a serialized array, but it isn't an array. Are you asking how to combine 2 different arrays in Swift? If so, you should show Swift code. Are you trying to combine an array that was created in swift and an array that was read from a JSON file?

Comment: @Duncan C ,yesi am trying to combine an array that was created in swift and an array that was read from a JSON file. i just want to add new array which i get it from api response.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your new data comes from JSON is irrelevant. You need to map the JSON into objects, and then appending objects to an array is easy:

```
var strings1 = ["a string", "another string"]  // This is a var, so it can be changed
let strings2 = ["a third string", "a fourth string"]
strings1 += strings2 //Use += to append strings2 to strings1
print(strings1)
```

The code above outputs

> ["a string", "another string", "a third string", "a fourth string"]

The code below does the same thing using an array of strings created from JSON:

```
//Create a string that contains the JSON for an array fo strings.
let jsonString = """
[
"a third string",
"a fourth string"
]
"""
//Convert the JSON string to Data, and convert the Data to a Swift array
if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8),
    let jsonArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String]
{
    var strings1 = ["a string", "another string"]
    strings1 += jsonArray
    print(strings1)
}
```